# Creating a batch-file to delete specific files

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

At first, I know this question probably exists, but on first sight I didn't find the answer I was looking for.

I'm having a problem creating a batch-file that should delete multiple files with their specific file format given as a parameter. The folder where these files should be is defined as the first parameter. Read-Only, hidden and system files should be deleted too.

So far I have something like this:

```
CD %1
IF EXIST *.%2 DEL *.%2  /F /A:H /A:S
```

But this doesn't has the result it should have...
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about...

```
CD /D %1
DEL *.%2  /F /A:H /A:S
```

The `/D` by the CD makes sure it also changes the current drive. By default CD will always stay in the same drive, no matter where you want to go.

Then, the `if exist` is pointless. If there is nothing to delete, `DEL` won't delete anything.

<strike>I'm not sure if `*.%2` is really what you want, because it will only match files with no name with a certain extension. You probably want only `%2`.</strike> It is.

If that doesn't work, please tell us what happens. You told us the expect result, namely that it should delete files in a given directory matching a given pattern. Tell us what happens instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My reason for using the '*.%2'-approach is because I aim to delete all files with that specific file pattern, but with any possible filename. Is this the wrong way to use it? Should I use a different notation? If I run it like that, with %2 as 'bat', for batch-files, it says it doesn't find the file named bat. (Can't find C:\batch-files\bat)

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you about this, but it still gives the same result (Can't find C:\batch-files\*.bat) Can't help thinking I'm doing something terribly wrong...

Comment: Is there a backslash between 'batch-files' and '*.bat'? If no, there should be one. If yes, does the file look like in my answer? If yes, turn 'echo off' and post the output. Are you sure that the directory 'C:\batch-files' exists and there are .bat files inside? How do you call the batch file?

Answer (score -5):

http://forums.techarena.in/windows-server-help/621875.htm

```
del /s *.tmp *.temp *.dmp
```

Next time, research your question first.

Comment: How about a bit less arrogance and reading the question first? Your approach does not allow for a user-defined pattern, it doesn't delete hidden, system, or read-only files, and it doesn't change to a directory.